# Javascript function only works on the first row only inside my modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, modal-dialog

I am using a javascript function for input verification where it is being used inside a modal. I click the edit button at the first row, javascript functions work well. But when I click on the edit button on the second row, and succeeding rows, it doesn't function.

I am not really sure if the problem is the data inside the modal or the data outside the modal

I tried adding a class name in the input fields and changing the calling function in javascript from "#name" to ".name" but it did not work.

I also tried the shown.bs function

// Here is my code for the table (partial)

```
    <?php
    if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_accounts)) {
    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <form action="update.php" method="POST">
    <td>
    <?php echo $row["username"]; ?> </td>
    <td>
    <?php echo $row["firstname"]; ?> </td>
    <td> .....
    <td>
    <?php echo $row["status"]; ?> </td>
    <td>
    <?php
    if ($row["status"] == "Deactivated") {
    ?>
    <a href="update.php?activate=<?php echo $row['accountid']; ?>" class="btn btn-info"> Activate </a>
    <?php
    } elseif ($row["status"] == "Active") {
    ?>
    <a href="update.php?deactivate=<?php echo $row['accountid']; ?>" class="btn btn-warning"> Deactivate </a>
    <?php
    } ?>
    <a href="#edit<?php echo $row['accountid']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal">Edit</a>
```

// Here is my code for the modal (partial)

```
    <div id="edit<?php echo $row['accountid']; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Account</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <form method="POST" action="editaccount.php">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" name="edit_item_id" value="<?php echo $row['accountid']; ?>">
    <label>Username</label>
    <span id="popover-username" class="pun hide pull-right block-help"><i class="fa fa-info-circle text-danger" aria-hidden="true"></i> Username must not contain any special characters</span>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="username form-control" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" placeholder="Enter Username">
```

//Here is my javascript function

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#password').keyup(function() {
                var password = $('#password').val();
                if (checkStrength(password) == false) {
                    $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });

            $('#confirm_password').blur(function() {
                if ($('#password').val() !== $('#confirm_password').val()) {
                    $('#popover-cpassword').removeClass('hide');
                    $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                } else {
                    $('#popover-cpassword').addClass('hide');
                    $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            });

            $('#username').blur(function() {
                var regex = /\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\""|\;|\:|\s/;
                if ($('#username').val().match(regex)) {
                    $('#popover-username').removeClass('hide');
                    $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                } else {
                    $('#popover-username').addClass('hide');
                    $('#sign-up').attr('disabled', false);
                    $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                }
            })

            $('#contact_number').blur(function() {
                var regex = /^[(9)][(\d+)]{9}$/;
                if ($('#contact_number').val().match(regex)) {
                    $('#popover-cnumber').addClass('hide');
                    $("#submit").removeAttr('disabled');
                } else {
                    $('#popover-cnumber').removeClass('hide');                        
                    $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });

            $('#password').keyup(function() {
                var password = $('#password').val();
                if (checkStrength(password) == false) {
                    $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                }
            });
```

A message should come out once an input is wrong, like for example I input # in the username field there should be a message user name must containany special character where the javascript function removes the class hide from the span code in the modal

Comment: You are binding your validation logic to id, and in this case you are getting the first valid input for this selector. You should bind all your stuff to class selector instead.

Comment: Is it correct to say you have one modal for each row of data?

Comment: @dganenco thank you! then i should change all '# 'to '.' and add an identifier in my class name in the input field like class="username form-control"??

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes, because per row in my table i have an edit button

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you need to do. Also I'm gonna provide you few improvements for your validations in a few minutes.

Comment: Then dganenco's intuition is correct. HTML `id` attributes must be unique. In this case each of the forms in the modals all have the exact same `id` attribute. You can't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned above you should use class selector and also I slightly improved your validations

```
$('.password').keyup(function() {
  $("#submit").prop('disabled', checkStrength($(this).val()) === false);
});

$('.confirm_password').blur(function() {
  var arePasswordTheSame = $('.password').val() !== $(this).val();
  $('.popover-cpassword').toggleClass('hide', !arePasswordTheSame);
  $("#submit").prop('disabled', !arePasswordTheSame)
});

$('.username').blur(function() {
  var regex = /\`|\~|\!|\@|\#|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\(|\)|\+|\=|\[|\{|\]|\}|\||\\|\'|\<|\,|\.|\>|\?|\/|\""|\;|\:|\s/;
  var isUserNameCorrect = $(this).val().match(regex);
  $('.popover-username').toggleClass('hide', !isUserNameCorrect);
  $(".submit").prop('disabled', !isUserNameCorrect);
  $('.sign-up').prop('disabled', !isUserNameCorrect);
})

$('.contact_number').blur(function() {
  var regex = /^[(9)][(\d+)]{9}$/;
  var isNumberCorrect = $(this).val().match(regex)
  $('.popover-cnumber').toggleClass('hide', !isNumberCorrect);
  $(".submit").prop('disabled', !isNumberCorrect);
});
```

Also you will need to add your current container to all class seelctors. For more info please reference [API](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Thank you sir! I followed what you said and also changed my javascript code. Except for the API yet. Although, when I open my first edit modal and add a special character and then close the modal then open another edit modal the alert from the first modal was still there. Is this because there was no API that you were sating sir?

Comment: Yes, lets imagine your first modal has class 'modal'. Then, you should use in each your validation function smth like this $('.modal:visible').find('.your_class').toggleClass. The main Idea is that you should always reference your currently opened modal dialog and do all your stuff only for it.

Comment: sir, maybe you could help me with my latest problem?

Comment: What is it you latest problem?

Answer (score 0):

This approach would work only if your php code generates one

Per each account, putting all of them in the html.